# Definition of ring homomorphism in Bosch's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, model-theory

In Bosch's Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra, I see that the definition of a ring homomorphism is a map that preserves the two operations and the unity; it isn't mentioned that it must preserve the zero (that, by the definition of a structure-preserving map, should be requested instead). I think that the motivation could be that, while for a subring $A$ of a ring $B$ can happen that $1_A\neq1_B$, the zero of a subgroup is always the zero of the ambient group (and the image of a map preserving the operations is a subring, so a subgroup, of the codomain). Is this actually the reason? Thanks

Comment: You pointed out a magnificent example of **bad** mathematical writing +1

Comment: Why should be mentioned that $f(0_A)=0_B$ if this follows from $f(a+a')=f(a)+f(a')$?

Comment: @PrimoPetri I wouldn't say that's bad writing, as it is an immediate consequence of the definition. I agree that one should mention this in a first course to abstract algebra but Bosch's book is more advanced and should assume that his readers are comfortable enough with rings.

Comment: @QiZhu There is nothing deep or convenient in the shorter definition. Computer scientist have the rule **explicit is better than implicit**. It should apply also for mathematical writing. (A full discussion on math writings would be OT here.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi : A \to B$ be your ring homomorphism.
Then
$\varphi (0_A) = \varphi(1_A - 1_A) = \varphi (1_A) - \varphi (1_A) =
1_B - 1_B = 0_B$

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning why a similar argument can't guarantee the map to preserve $1_A$.

Comment: The property holds for group homomorphisms, so why use the unities?